# Set element max length

Tags: javascript, jquery

searching here for an answer I found the following question:

[Answer for similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551502/set-max-length-for-content-editable-element)

I'm trying to replicate this answer but in a different scenario and seems that it doesn't work when I call a function instead of jQuery key events on document.ready().

This is what I have:

```js
function maxLenght(event) {
  var input = $('p[data-id="111"]').get(0);

  if (parseInt(input.textContent.length) >= 10 && event.keyCode != 8) {
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    $(input).outerHeight(32).outerHeight(input.scrollHeight + 4);
  }
        
  $('span').text('Total chars:' + (input).textContent.length);
}
```

```css
p {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p contenteditable="true" data-id="111" onkeyup="maxLenght(event)"></p>
<span></span>
```

Also I should be able to paste text using right click or ctrl + v, navigate the text using arrow keys, backspace, delete key, etc.

So my question is if is possible to do it keeping this functionallity (calling a function) and how can I do it and what's wrong from what I have right now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onkeydown` instead of `onkeyup`.

```html
<p contenteditable="true" data-id="111" onkeyup="maxLenght(event)"></p>
```

### EDIT

Backspace cannot be used to delete characters whose length is more than or equal to the given limit. Rather, add a condition to the if statement stating that it accepts the backspace key.

```js
...
if (parseInt(input.textContent.length) >= 10 && event.key !== "Backspace") {
    event.preventDefault();
}
...
```

Comment: If I add onkeydown now I can't type more than 10 chars however, I can paste more than 10 chars and also I'm not able to copy the text in the element.

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: `event.keyCode` is deprecated. Use `event.key` instead.

Comment: Seems to work in a manual scenario but I'm still able to paste a string with more than 10 chars and also I can't copy the element content.